# how to update default status of any record using django rest framework

Tags: django, angular

I have three buttons named start, stop and cancel in my project. There is a status field which is default registered. When the 'start' button is clicked, the status should update 'running'. When the 'close' button is clicked, the status should update 'closed'. When the 'cancel' button is clicked, the status should update 'cancelled'.

```py
@csrf_exempt

def projectApi(request,id=0):

    if request.method=='GET':
        project = Project.objects.all()
        project_serializer = ProjectSerializer(project, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(project_serializer.data, safe=False)
        

    elif request.method=='POST':
        
        project_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        project_serializer = ProjectSerializer(data=project_data)
        if project_serializer.is_valid():
            project_serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse("Added Successfully!!", safe=False)
        return JsonResponse("Failed to Add",safe=False)
```

This is my `views.py` file.